# No collision between meshes in Babylon.js using Cannon.js

Tags: collision, babylonjs, cannon.js

`I created a mesh from a heightmap and gave it a collision heighfield. I then created a sphere that falls and is supposed to collide with said heightfield. Physics using CANNNON.js are all set up, but there is no collision between the two. I even tried using the Havok Engine but I prefer CANNON.js.

Babylon.js file:

```
        const canvas = document.getElementById("renderCanvas"); // Get the canvas element
    const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true); // Generate the BABYLON 3D engine

    // Add your code here matching the playground format
    const createScene = async function() {
    const scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    
    var cannonJSPlugin = new BABYLON.CannonJSPlugin();
    // Create a Cannon.js world
    var world = new CANNON.World();
    // Set the gravity vector for the physics simulation
    cannonJSPlugin.setGravity(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, -9.81, 0));
    
    /*
    world.gravity.set(0, -9.81, 0); // Set the world's gravity
    world.broadphase = new CANNON.NaiveBroadphase(); // Use the NaiveBroadphase
    */
    // Set the physics engine of the scene to use Cannon.js
    scene.enablePhysics(new BABYLON.Vector3(0, -9.81, 0), cannonJSPlugin);
    
    const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera("camera", -Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 2.5, 3, new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
        camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
        camera.position.y = 10;
    
    const light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight("light", new BABYLON.Vector3(1, 1, 0));
        light.intensity = 0.7;
    
    
    const astMat = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("astMat");
        astMat.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("http://fagnanialessiohtml.altervista.org/img/textures/rockyPlanet.png", scene);
    
    const sphere = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateSphere("sphere", { diameter: 2, segments: 32 }, scene);
        sphere.material = astMat;
        sphere.position.y = 100;        
        sphere.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(sphere, BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.SphereImpostor, { mass: 1.0, restitution: 1.0 }, scene);
        sphere.checkCollisions = true;
    
    const groundMat = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("groundMat");
        groundMat.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("http://fagnanialessiohtml.altervista.org/img/solarsystem/moon_texture.jpg");

    var ground = BABYLON.Mesh.CreateGroundFromHeightMap("ground", "http://fagnanialessiohtml.altervista.org/img/textures/heightmap-3.jpg", 300, 150, 20, 0, 20, scene, false)
        ground.material = groundMat;
    
    // Get the heightmap data from the ground mesh
    var heightmap = ground.getVerticesData(BABYLON.VertexBuffer.PositionKind);

    // Check if the heightmap data is not null or undefined
    if (heightmap) {
        // Calculate the matrix size from the heightmap data
        var matrixSize = Math.sqrt(heightmap.length / 3);

        // Create the Cannon.js heightfield shape that matches the heightmap data
        var heightfieldShape = new CANNON.Heightfield(heightmap, {
            elementSize: 100 / (matrixSize - 1)
        });

        // Create a Cannon.js body for the ground mesh
        var groundBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0 });
        groundBody.addShape(heightfieldShape);
        groundBody.position.set(0, 0, 0);

        // Add the Cannon.js body to the physics world
        world.addBody(groundBody);

        // Link the Babylon.js mesh to the Cannon.js body
        ground.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(
            ground,
            BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.NoImpostor, {
                mass: 0,
                restitution: 0.5
                  },
                  scene
              );
              ground.physicsImpostor.setPhysicsBody(groundBody);
    }
        ground.checkCollisions = true;  
          
    
    return scene;
  };
   
  createScene().then((scene) => {
    engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
      if (scene) {
        scene.render();
      }
    });
  });

  // Watch for browser/canvas resize events
  window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    engine.resize();
  });
```